# Eclipse IDE : Change font of line numbers pane

Tags: eclipse

I try to found settings to configure font of line number pane in Eclipse settings, but no success. So, is available? May be i can found it in some conf file and change manually.

In my case i want to change line number pane font from regular to bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that's not possible. You can only set the line number font together with the font of the editor (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts).